# ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from partially initialized module 'flask' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 87):

I have removed the error by just not saving the file as "flask.py"

Comment: Yes the  issue is that flask.py naming convention and Import flask command are causing this issue whereas if youu run this code in jupyter notebook without saving the notebook or keeping some other name will work .